# Definition of Undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, c, standards, undefined-behavior

I have read on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) about Undefined behavior and understand the differences. What I didn't find though is what is implicit.

I would expect any behavior that is not explicitly defined to be unspecified behavior. But when I tried to find what `t` means in `fopen`'s format string, there was nothing in the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) on it and nowhere does it state that it is implementation defined. What bugs me even more is that in notes it is explicitly stated about the `filename` parameter.

On the other hand [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) defines among others the `t` parameter so that would mean that any behavior not explicitly stated as undefined can be implementation defined? Or is the cppreference just missing a sentence and I'm only chasing ghosts?

I guess what the question boils down for me is, if there is nothing written about something, what is it, undefined or implementation defined behavior?

PS. The question is about general case so please don't tell me how to use `fopen` "the right way" in the answers. The function was just an example.

Comment: If the standard says nothing about it then it is left up to the implementation on how to do X or Y, it might not have X but have Y or vice versa, Y might blow up your computer, etc etc.

Comment: This is C or C++? Two are different languages, you know.

Comment: The difference between this sort of implementation defined and the one that's specified in the standard is that any compliant c++ compiler _must_ implement the "implementation defined" behaviour, there just are no rules on how to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior?rq=1

Comment: The standard defines how some things are supposed to work, if it doesn't define then behavior is, you guessed it, undefined. Yes, behavior can be implementation, or architecture defined. Though generally we say it's "undefined behavior" when your code is doing something sketchy that is most likely going to cause a crash.

Comment: Read the entire documentation – scrolling down on that MSDN page you linked to: "The c, n, t, S, R, T, and D mode options are Microsoft extensions for fopen".

Comment: cppreference updated to mention fopen's spec for unknown modes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document to read about undefined / implementation-defined behaviour is the relevant standard for the language; i.e. for C for example the latest standard document is "ISO/IEC 9899:2011", also known as C11. As these are not freely available to public, we often use the last public working draft instead. For C11 the last public working draft is n1570, which is available at least at [port70.net](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html).

---

The C11 standard explicitly says the following of "undefined behaviour":

> 1 In this International Standard, ''shall'' is to be interpreted as a requirement on an implementation or on a program; conversely, ''shall not'' is to be interpreted as a prohibition.
>
> 2 If a **shall** or **shall not** requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words **undefined behavior** or *by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior*. There is no difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe **behavior that is undefined**.

Thus any behaviour that is not explicitly defined in the standard, is, when it comes to the standard, is undefined, and every possible imaginable and unimaginable behaviour is equally acceptable.

---

Now, different implementations, like MSVC or GCC can give stronger guarantees for certain constructs - they can document that a certain behaviour can be expected in that implementation. However, if one wants to write *portable* C code, relying on such behaviour should be avoided.

---

As for `fopen`, the [C11 7.21.5.3p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p3) says that

> The argument mode points to a string. If the string is one of the following, the file is open in the indicated mode. *Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*

(emphasis mine)

And the list contains only `r`, `w`, `wx`, `a`, `rb`, `wb`, `wbx`, `ab`, `r+`, `w+`, `w+x`, `a+`, `r+b`, `rb+`, `w+b`, `wb+`, `w+bx`, `wb+x`, `a+b` and `ab+`; thus given a mode string with `t` in it, the particular `fopen` implementation is free to do absolutely anything it sees fit, including:

- opening a file in text mode
- opening a file in binary mode
- opening a file for appending
- crashing
- **t**runcating a file
- returning an error
- opening a file with transparent **t**ranslation into **T**urkish
- or any other behaviour

Yet the implementation can still be standard-conforming.

Answer (score 2):

If no behavior at all is specified, the behavior is undefined. This is guaranteed by the definition of undefined behavior (C11):

> 3.4.3
>   **undefined behavior**
>   behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this
>   International Standard imposes no requirements

Together with chapter 4 §2 regarding conformance:

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a
>   constraint or runtime constraint is violated, the behavior is
>   undefined. Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this
>   International Standard by the words ‘‘undefined behavior’’ or by the
>   omission of any explicit definition of behavior. There is no
>   difference in emphasis among these three; they all describe ‘‘behavior
>   that is undefined’’.

---

As for your specific example, it does not apply here since `fopen` explicitly says that unknown formats give undefined behavior. The `fopen` function is specified in C11 7.21.5.3:

> The argument `mode` points to a string. If the string is one of the following, the file is open in the indicated mode. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

(list of allowed formats follows)